# App crash on view change

Tags: android

Im trying to make the contentView change on a button click, but the app crash when i start it by some reason.

This is my onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
     b1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) mHandler);
    mHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.bStart:
                  // it was the first button
                    setContentView(R.layout.cards);
                  break;

              }
          }
    };}
```

Comment: crashing because you are not calling `setContentView` before using `findViewById`

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize `mHandler` before you set it to `b1.setOnClickListener`

Comment: post your logcat. That is the best way to narrow down the source of the crash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. `setContentView()` method should be called only once in `onCreate()` method and it shouldn't be invoked by clicking the button. In addtion, `findViewById()` methods should be called after calling `setContentView()` method. If you want to replace your layout, consider using fragments or do some manipulation on the views inside the layout without calling `setContentView()` method again.